# Simplifying $\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

To simplify:
$$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}.$$

I know that in the denominator, $\sin(2x)$ can be re-written as $2\sin x\cos x$ using the double-angle identity.

I also know that for the numerator $\sin(3x)+\sin(5x)=2\sin(4x)\cos x$ and likewise for the denominator $\sin x+\sin(3x)=2\sin(2x)\cos x$.

After that, I get:
$$\frac{2\sin(4x)\cos x +\sin(4x)}{2\sin(2x)\cos x + 2\sin x\cos x}.$$

If necessary, the $\sin(4x)$ in the numerator can also become $2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$. This would make the fraction:

$$\frac{2\sin(4x)\cos x + 2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{2\sin(2x)\cos x + 2\sin x\cos x}.$$

From here, one can factor out a two from both numerator and denominator and thereby cancel them out (though I'm not sure this is helpful in the long run):

$$\frac{\sin(4x)\cos x +\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)\cos x +\sin x\cos x}.$$

And then, stuck. No like terms that I can see and which identity is helpful here, I do not know. Can someone help with some hints for the next steps in order to simplify?

Comment: Just off the top of my head: you can use $\sin {(4x)} = 2\sin(2x) \cos(2x)$ in the numerator (at which you arrived), enabling you to cancel out all the $\sin (2x)$'s.

Comment: I find the answer comes relatively easily (without needing any identities until near the end) if you think of the sines as components of unit vectors and do most of the work via vector addition. But you could also just keep on with the double-angle sine formula and get the answer that way too.

Comment: If you plot it, you see the result as $2cos(2x)$

Answer (score 13):

$$\frac{\sin(3x) + \sin(4x) + \sin(5x)}{\sin(x) + \sin(2x) + \sin(3x)}$$

$$= \frac{\sin(4x) + (\sin(5x) + \sin(3x))}{\sin(2x) + (\sin(3x) + \sin(x))}$$

$$=\frac{\sin(4x) + 2\sin(4x)\cos(x)}{\sin(2x) + 2\sin(2x)\cos(x)}$$

$$=\frac{\sin(4x)(1+2\cos(x))}{\sin(2x)(1+2\cos(x))}$$

$$=\frac{2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}$$

$$= 2\cos(2x)$$

Answer (score 12):

Let $z=e^{ix}.$

$$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}=$$
$$\frac{z^3-z^{-3}+z^4-z^{-4}+z^5-z^{-5}}{z-z^{-1}+z^2-z^{-2}+z^3-z^{-3}}=$$$$z^2+z^{-2}=2\cos(2x).$$

(For the central step, simply check that the denominator times $z^2+z^{-2}$ equals the numerator.)

Comment: This answer would be better if you showed the intermediate results between step 2 and step 3.

Comment: (Done, 9 min later.)

Comment: That's a clever use of Euler's Theorem!

Answer (score 3):

An approach with vectors:

Let
\begin{align}
v_1 &= (\cos x, \sin x), \\
v_2 &= (\cos (2x), \sin (2x)), \\
v_3 &= (\cos (3x), \sin (3x)), \\
v_4 &= (\cos (4x), \sin (4x)), \\
v_5 &= (\cos (5x), \sin (5x)).
\end{align}

The vectors $v_1$ and $v_3$ are symmetric around $v_2$, so their sum is a vector along the same line as $v_2$. You can work out geometrically that the sum is

$$ v_1 + v_3 = (2\cos x) v_2. $$

Therefore

$$ v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = (1 + 2\cos x) v_2. $$

The vectors $v_3$ and $v_5$ likewise are symmetric around $v_4$ and their sum is along the same line as $v_4$,

$$ v_3 + v_5 = (2\cos x) v_4. $$

and therefore

$$ v_3 + v_4 + v_5 = (1 + 2\cos x) v_4. $$

So we have $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = r v_2$ and $v_3 + v_4 + v_5 = r v_4$ with
$r = 1 + 2\cos x$.

Intuitively, it is not even necessary to work out the exact value of $r$ as long as you recognize that the three vectors $v_3,v_4,v_5$ have the exact same geometry as $v_1,v_2,v_3$ except that the entire set of vectors is rotated, and therefore whatever multiple of $v_2$ we get from $v_1 + v_2 + v_3$, we get the same multiple of $v_4$
from $v_3 + v_4 + v_5$.

Now if we take the second component of each vector on each side of each equation
$v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = r v_2$ and $v_3 + v_4 + v_5 = r v_4$, we get

\begin{align}
\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x) &= r\sin(2x), \\
\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x) &= r\sin(4x),
\end{align}
which we know is true because we can do the vector addition componentwise.

It follows that
$$
\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}
= \frac{r \sin(4x)}{r \sin(2x)},
$$
and you can finish simplifying it from there.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have shown, you have already bypassed the quick solution methods.

But if you continue from here:
$$
\frac{\sin(4x)\cos x +\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)\cos x +\sin x\cos x}
$$

by repeatedly applying the double-angle formula for sine, you get

$$
\frac{2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\cos x + 2\sin x\cos x\cos(2x)}{(2\sin x\cos x)\cos x +\sin x\cos x},
$$

then

$$
\frac{(4\sin x\cos x)\cos(2x)\cos x + 2\sin x\cos x\cos(2x)}{(2\sin x\cos x)\cos x +\sin x\cos x}.
$$

Now you have a factor of $\sin x$ and also a factor of $\cos x$ in each term.
Cancel them out:
$$
\frac{4\cos(2x)\cos x + 2\cos(2x)}{2\cos x + 1}.
$$

At this point, think about factoring the numerator. You have an obvious factor of $\cos(2x)$ and a factor of $2$. Once you factor those out of the numerator,
the answer should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [@Anne Bauval's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771266/simplifying-frac-sin3x-sin4x-sin5x-sinx-sin2x-sin3x/4771272#4771272), but with slightly different intermediate steps.

Let $z = e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$.  Then

$$z^n = e^{inx} = \cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)$$
$$z^{-n} = e^{-inx} = \cos(nx) - i\sin(nx)$$

so $\cos(nx) = \frac{z^n + z^{-n}}{2}$ and $\sin(nx) = \frac{z^n - z^{-n}}{2i}$.  Thus:

$$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{z^3 - z^{-3}}{2i}+\frac{z^4 - z^{-4}}{2i}+\frac{z^5 - z^{-5}}{2i}}{\frac{z - z^{-1}}{2i}+\frac{z^2 - z^{-2}}{2i}+\frac{z^3 - z^{-3}}{2i}}  $$
$$=\frac{z^5 + z^4 + z^3 - z^{-3} - z^{-4} - z^{-5}}{z^3 +z^2 + z - z^{-1} - z^{-2} - z^{-3}}$$
$$=\frac{z^{10} + z^9 + z^8 - z^{2} - z - 1}{z^8 +z^7 + z^6 - z^{4} - z^{3} - z^{2}}$$

Doing polynomial long division, and factoring the $z^2$ out of the denominator, simplifies this to:

$$=z^2 + \frac{z^{6} + z^{5} + z^{4} - z^{2} - z - 1}{z^2(z^6 +z^5 + z^4 - z^{2} - z - 1)}$$
$$=z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}$$
$$=2\cos(2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, let $s = \sin(x)$ and $c = \cos(x)$.

Recall DeMoivre's Formula:

$$\cos(nx) + i\sin(nx) = (c + is)^n$$

We can expand the RHS using the Binomial Theorem:

$$\cos(2x) + i\sin(2x) = c^2 + 2ics - s^2$$
$$\cos(3x) + i\sin(3x) = c^3 + 3ic^2s - 3cs^2 - is^3$$
$$\cos(4x) + i\sin(4x) = c^4 + 4ic^3s - 6c^2s^2 - 4ics^3 + s^4$$
$$\cos(5x) + i\sin(5x) = c^5 + 5ic^4s - 10c^3s^2 - 10ic^2s^3 + 5cs^4 + is^5$$

Taking the imaginary parts of each equation gives us formulas for $\sin(nx)$.  (And taking the real parts gives us formula's for $\cos(nx)$.)

$$\sin(2x) = 2cs$$
$$\sin(3x) = 3c^2s - s^3$$
$$\sin(4x) = 4c^3s - 4cs^3$$
$$\sin(5x) = 5c^4s - 10c^2s^3 + s^5$$

Plugging these expressions into the one from your question gives:

$$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}$$
$$=\frac{3c^2s - s^3+4c^3s - 4cs^3+5c^4s - 10c^2s^3 + s^5}{s+2cs+3c^2s - s^3}$$
$$=\frac{3c^2 - s^2 + 4c^3 - 4cs^2 + 5c^4 - 10c^2s^2 + s^4}{1+2c+3c^2 - s^2}$$

At this point, all of the powers of $s$ are even, so let's make the Pythagorean substitution $s^2 = 1 - c^2$, so that we only have one variable to deal with.

$$=\frac{3c^2 - (1 - c^2) + 4c^3 - 4c(1 - c^2) + 5c^4 - 10c^2(1 - c^2) + (1 - c^2)^2}{1+2c+3c^2 - (1 - c^2)}$$
$$=\frac{3c^2 - 1 + c^2 + 4c^3 - 4c + 4c^3 + 5c^4 - 10c^2 + 10c^4 + 1 - 2c^2 + c^4}{1+2c+3c^2 - 1 + c^2}$$
$$=\frac{16c^4 + 8c^3 - 8c^2 - 4c}{4c^2 + 2c}$$
$$=\frac{2(2c^2 - 1)(2c + 1)}{2c + 1}$$
$$=2 (2c^2 - 1)$$
$$=2\cos(2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 \cos (2 x)[\sin x+\sin (2 x)+\sin (3 x)] = & {[\sin (3 x)-\sin x]+\sin (4 x) } +[\sin (5 x)+\sin x] \\
= & \sin (3 x)+\sin (4 x)+\sin (5 x),
\end{aligned}
$$
we have
$$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)+\sin(2x)+\sin(3x)}=2\cos(2x)$$